# C++ Array Error: Access violation reading location 0xC0000005

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio-2013

For some reason, when I try to print out an array of strings it always has an error:

> Unhandled exception at 0x0F767EA6 (msvcp120d.dll) in Project1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x73F6B6FF.

Here is the code that generates the error:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int numItems = 6;
    string itemNames[numItems] = { "Boots", "Swords", "Helmets", "Kittens", "Poleaxes", "Leggings" };

    cout << "*** Welcome to the item shop! ***\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < numItems; i++)
    {
        cout << itemNames[numItems] << endl;
    }

    cout << "**********\n\n";
    cout << "What would you like to buy?\n";

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

I am using Visual Studio 2013, by the way.

Comment: `system("PAUSE")` is not how you pause for input in C++. Use `cin` like you're supposed to.

Comment: @tadman What are you talking about? That is to stop Visual Studio from stopping the program before I see the program output. I did comment that I used Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: If you're waiting on input from the user, the program won't exit. Using `pause` is super hack.

Comment: `system("PAUSE")` makes it so that if you press any key, the program will exit. `cin` won't because you need to program it to terminate the program when a key is entered and that wastes time.

Comment: It'll wait until you press enter, that's for sure. if you want to wait for a single keypress that's also an option, but more annoying. Using external tools like that limits the portability of your application, that's why I mention it. If you're doing Windows development, it really should be in a window with an "OK" button to close it.

Comment: I'm not using external tools, just Visual Studio 2013. Anyway, I'm not too advanced in C++ programming and I'm not so sure how to an 'OK' button. As you (should) see, this is a basic program so I don't know what you are on about. This whole argument is set on the basis on 'pausing for input in C++' which I do not need to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < numItems; i++)
{
    cout << itemNames[numItems] << endl;
}
```

You may want `cout << itemNames[i] << endl;`. Otherwise `itemNames[numItems]` is always out-of-bound.

Comment: Not sure why you didn't change this in the snippet you added.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `numItems` is `6`. You are trying to access `itemNames[6]` with `itemNames[numItems]` in line

> cout << itemNames[numItems] << endl;

which doesn't exist. And thus you get an access violation error.